Forking and piping under windows
use Child qw/child/;

my @childs;
for my $i (1 .. 65) {
    push @childs, child {
        my $parent = shift;

        $parent->say("[return $i]");
    } pipe => 1;
}

print $_->read for @childs;

the above code doesn't print anything under strawberry 5.38.2
It does however when number of childs is 64. Is there a way to avoid such limit?

eh... doesn't make sense to use fork in Windows, since it's (poorly) emulated by threads. Just use threads.

As for having more than 64 child threads/processes, perhaps you're not using the right approach...

any ideas how it will reflect on memory consumption?

btw, @schwern comment under https://stackoverflow.com/a/16258675/223226

You mean if you switch to using threads directly instead of pretending to use fork? That will have no effect on memory consumption since you're already using threads. /// Each thread creates a copy of the interpreter, including all variables therein. This conveniently emulates the behaviour of fork (without the benefits of COW, except for the loaded shared libraries).

schwern's comment isn't relevant here since you're not forking. Again, fork is emulated using threads in Windows.

tnx, I'll switch to threads

what clarity do you want the one who wants to close the question?

See second comment. What are you trying to accomplish? You're asking an XY problem. You talk about "Forking and piping under windows", which isn't even possible.* (* Cygwin found a way to do it using Windows internals. But it's not possible using the public API. So it's effectively impossible to fork in Windows.)

@mpapec  "what clarity ..."  I regularly see close votes on Perl questions which I can't really understand. (It appears that every N-th question, for very small N's, has a close vote, and right after it's posted!)  I guess people have their criteria and reading of SO rules.
